How does mathematical atomism do away with the classical conception of man?
I've been reading E.A. Burtt, The Metaphysical Foundations of Modern Science. I keep going back to Galileo and his idea of motion, space, and time. I still can't internalize what he means by man losing his place in the universe. I get that the classics held man as the intermediary between the corporeal realm and God, with his purpose being union with God. But Burtt states that to conceive of 'time' as a linear straight line (borne out of the atomistic, religiously mathematical zeal) where the past is gone, the future does not exist, and the present is but the boundary between the two constantly moving "forced" Galileo to reject the classical view of man. I can't seem to draw the connection. How does mathematical atomism do away with the classical conception of man?

Regarding the Scientific Revolution and the "place of man in the universe" see at least Alexandre Koyré's works.

"Man losing his place"... went from... possibly the only reality at the center of everything... to being one of observable gajillions and the center of nothing but our own tiny little insignificant corner of an absoltely massive and numerously populated cosmos.  Quite the come-uppance for those wishing it plausible to think we are the reason it all exists when evidence reveals us to be but a speck... and speck isbeing generous.  We went from potentially special and significant to observably not.  "Lost our place" as king of a pretend castle.

Frankly speaking, I'm not sure to fully understand waht "Galileo rejection of the classical view of man" means...
We can see a modern commentary into H.Floris Cohen, The Scientific Revolution: A Historiographical Inquiry (1994), Ch.2.3.4 Burrt and the Mathematization of Nature, page 88-on.
Regarding Burtt's text, we can see Ch.III (D), page 91-on, where the Author discusses Galileo's fundamental contribution to the changing the view of space and time:

"The real world is the world of bodies in mathematically reducible motions, and this means that the real world is a world of bodies moving in space and time."

The following speculations (page 95, see ref to Bergson) regarding the modern conception of time vs the Medieval one can be relevant (maybe) to understand the modern worldview, but they have little connection with Galileo's work; the historical fact is (page 96) that "Galileo's exact study of velocities and accelerations forced him to devise a simple technique for the geometrical representation of time."
This is IMo the key-point: science may or may not have metaphysical sources and may or may not have metaphysical consequences, but it has results and techniques that are based on facts and measurement and thus objective.

"Galileo's exact study of velocities and accelerations forced him to devise a simple technique for the geometrical representation of time."How does the "exact study of velocities and accelerations" force him to devise a simple technique for the geometrical representation of time?
